# Python import csv file and replace blank values

Tags: python, csv

I have just started a data quality class in which I got zero instruction on Python but am expected to create a script. There are three instructions for my Python script:

1. Create a script that loads an entire CSV file and replace all the blank values to NAN
2. Use genfromtxt function
3. Write the results set into a different file

I have been working on this for a few hours, but with no previous experience with Python, I am completely stuck! This is what I have so far:

```
import csv

file = open(quality.csv, 'r')
csvreader = csv.reader(file)
header = next(csvreader)
print(header)
rows = []
for row in csvreader:
    rows.append(row)
print(rows)
```

My first problem is that when I tried using genfromtxt, it would not print out the headers or the entire csv file, it would only print out a few lines. If it matters, all of the values of the csv file are ints/floats, but the headers are strings.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUzQ1.png)

The next problem is I have tried several different ways to replace blank values, but I was not successful. All of the blank fields in this file are in the last column. When I print out the csv in full, this is what the line looks like (I've highlighted the empty value):

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGwXj.png)

Finally, I have no idea what instruction #3 means. I am completely new at this with zero Python knowledge! I think I am unsure of the Python syntax and rules - which I will look into more and learn, however I only had two days to complete this assignment and I do not know anything yet! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're supposed to be using NumPy's **genfromtxt**.  I've never used it, but here's a complete tutorial on it, https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html. Why did you get into this class if you have no Python experience? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you did with genfromtxt seems correct already. With big data like this, terminal only shows some data from the beginning and at the end, and those 3 dots in the middle also indicates the other records you're not seeing there!